# "Username already taken" double tap

Tags: ios, uialertview

When using the **sign up flow** in my app the **alert view** shows *"Username already taken"* when I double tap the signup button fast even though it's not taken. Is there a way to make sure that it want show the alert view when this happens or any other solution?

See my code below:

```
NSString *username = [self.usernameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *email = [self.emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([username length] == 0 || [password length]  == 0 || [email length] == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                        message:@"Make sure you enter a username, password, and email address with at least 5 characters!"
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];                
    [alertView show];
}
else {
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.password = password;
    newUser.email = email;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!"
                                                                message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"]
                                                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        else 
        {

            [self saveUserDefaults];                
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];                
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"setupProfile" sender:self];
        }

    }];

}
```

}

Comment: Disable the button after the first tap?

Comment: Super thanks. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Yes. Presumably you have an action method called by the button that you can use...

Comment: Of course. Or a BOOL maybe. But any ideas?

Comment: UIButton *buttonThatWasPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    buttonThatWasPressed.enabled = NO;

Works in ios7! If anyone needs it

Answer (score 1):

set

> setUserInteractionEnabled:NO

to your button on the First tap.

Which wont allow any tap until you set it

> setUserInteractionEnabled:YES

Comment: Thanks. How would that look like?

Comment: UIView* view = ( UIView* ) sender; [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];